# Calculated crossover frequency of Op Amp integrator doesn't match the simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am calculated the crossover frequency of my integrator circuit with the following formula.

\$ f_{0\text{ dB}} = \frac{1}{2\pi R_1 C_1} \approx \underline{\underline{154\text{ Hz}}}\$

[image: Schematic of my integrator circuit in LTSpice.]

Unhappily, the simulator LTSpice tell me a very different value.

[image: Result of the measurement command in LTSpice.]

Hopefully someone can help out of this rookie mistake I have overseen in my thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `AC 3` as the source, which means that if you want to calculate the **relative** 0 dB point you need to either:

- use `.meas f1 when mag(V(out))=3`;
- use `.meas f2 when mag(V(out))/mag(V(sine_f))=1`;
- use `AC 1` with your `.meas` command.

For all three cases, LTspice shows `154.749`, even when used with a very cheap 10 points/dec (but since this is a slope it works well enough). BTW, if you divide `467.185 / 154.749 ~ 3.02`. Not lastly, don't forget that the limited I/O impedances, or the GBW, may influence the result, especially when it looks like you're after an ideal integrator configuration -- in practice there's a resistor across the capacitor (1 MΩ, or higher), to provide a DC path.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I will leave the feedback resistor away, because I will reset the integrator by a switch. I had read, this is also a commonly used method. Possibly this is also good stuff for a new question, but do you have any recommendations for resetting the integration? My plan is to use an analog switch like the [MX418](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-switches-multiplexers/DG418.html).

Comment: @Daniel Sounds like a new question but, sure, you could use something like that, if you can't coerce a simpler JFET to do it (high signal levels, for example).